# error: incompatible types: AppCompatEditText cannot be converted to String

Tags: android, android-edittext, incompatibility, android-textinputedittext

I want to send data from registration From to the Firebase. I used the design library and used appcompactEditTex instead of simple EditText

Comment: add the code what you are trying, we don't have super powers to predict your code

Comment: please add some code where you are getting issue

Comment: My guess is you're missing a getText() call somewhere.

Comment: final String Useremail = email.getText().toString();
        i can get text thought that method form edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `editText.getText().toString()` to get the actual string

Comment: final String Useremail = email.getText().toString();
                final String userPassword = password.getText().toString();

Comment: i can get string throughth that method

Comment: Can or cannot? what do email and password represent? aren't they AppCompatEditTexts?